# Entity Framework 5.0 1:1 relationship Model-First

Tags: c#, entity-framework

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [1:1 relationship problems with EF Model First](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14016035/11-relationship-problems-with-ef-model-first)

Is there a way to define 1:1 relationships on a Entity Framework .edmx without get this annoying:

> Error 1   Running transformation: Multiplicity is not valid in Role
>   'PESSOACPF' in relationship 'FK_CPF_PES'. Because the Dependent
>   Role properties are not the key properties, the upper bound of the
>   multiplicity of the Dependent Role must be
>   *.

Already defined the FK as PK on my table, removed the pk, tried to re-create the project over 10 times and doesn't help AT ALL.

Comment: Are the tables connected PK to PK? That works for me.

Comment: Are you on EF 5? Yes, they are connected. Yet EF loves to do 1:* relationships.

Comment: Looks like EF is bugged. I removed one of the PK's and it worked.

That way i cant

Comment: Yes, but I'm doing code-first (it's same behind the scenes). I do not have access to VS here, so will not be able to verify.

Comment: Welll its just another EF "feature".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your **Foreign Key must be defined as UNIQUE**.

To enforce a 1:0 or 1:1 relationship.

You can create Table in SQL DB like this (Lets take Order and OrderDetails Tables)):

```
CREATE TABLE OrderDetails (
    DetailsId INTEGER IDENTITY NOT NULL,
    orderId INTEGER NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    PRIMARY KEY (DetailsId),
    FOREIGN KEY (orderId) REFERENCES Order(orderId)
)
```

For more details [**Implementing one-to-zero-or-one relation in SQL Server**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7644156/implementing-one-to-zero-or-one-relation-in-sql-server)

I hope this will help to you.